# Why the LD_PRELOAD trick does not work for librt?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, linker, ld

I was trying to apply the LD_PRELOAD trick to some proprietary binary. I've done similar things before, but no luck this time. The call I tried to intercept was timer_settime().

Strace clearly shows that timer_settime() was called by the binary:

```
[pid 30500] timer_settime(0x2, 0, {it_interval={30, 0}, it_value={30, 0}}, {it_interval={0, 0}, it_value={0, 0}}) = 0
```

It was called many times with different time intervals. I want to catch exactly the above one with an interval of 30 seconds.

Here's my code, timerwrap.c:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int timer_settime(timer_t timerid, int flags, const struct itimerspec *new_value, struct itimerspec *old_value)
{
    printf("Enter timer.\n");

    if((new_value->it_interval).tv_sec == 30) {
        printf("Catched!\n");
        return 0;
    }

    int (*real_timer_settime)(timer_t, int, const struct itimerspec *, struct itimerspec *);
    real_timer_settime = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "timer_settime");
    return real_timer_settime(timerid, flags, new_value, old_value);
}
```

gcc commandline:

```
gcc -Wall -g -shared -fPIC  -o timerwrap.so timerwrap.c -ldl -lrt
```

run program:

```
export LD_PRELOAD=/home/Work/C/timerwrap.so
./the_program
```

But it failed to intercept the call.

I ran it again with LD_DEBUG=all to further investigate. It turns out that for many other symbols, timerwrap.so was looked up, for example dlsym's lookup path looks like this in the debug output:

```
2006:   symbol=dlsym;  lookup in file=/.../the_program [0]
2006:   symbol=dlsym;  lookup in file=/home/Work/C/timerwrap.so [0]
2006:   symbol=dlsym;  lookup in file=./lib/libssl.so.6 [0]
2006:   symbol=dlsym;  lookup in file=/lib/i686/cmov/libdl.so.2 [0]
2006:   binding file /.../the_program [0] to /lib/i686/cmov/libdl.so.2 [0]: normal symbol `dlsym' [GLIBC_2.0]
```

However, for timer_settime, the lookup takes only one step, and goes directly to /usr/lib/librt.so, bypasses timerwrap.so:

```
2006:   symbol=timer_settime;  lookup in file=/usr/lib/librt.so [0]
2006:   binding file /usr/lib/librt.so [0] to /usr/lib/librt.so [0]: normal symbol `timer_settime'
```

So what happened here? Why is librt.so special? Any thoughts?

This is my first question. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2):

A simple example program shows me that everything works as it should.

The application you try to use, probably loads the `timer_settime` via `dlsym`.

Doing `dlsym(dlopen("librt.so"), "timer_settime")`

Solving this problem shouldn't be that hard, just add something like this to your source:

```
extern void *_dl_sym (void *handle, const char *name, void *who);
void *dlsym(void *handle, const char *symbol) 
{ 
        printf("Enter dlsym.\n");
        void* result = _dl_sym(handle, symbol, 0); // the replacement we are going to use 
        if ((handle != RTLD_NEXT) || (handle != RTLD_DEFAULT))
        if(!strcmp(symbol, "timer_settime")) { 
               printf("Return our timer_settime");
               return timer_settime;
        } 
        return result; 
}
```